# overloading multivalued constructor for dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, constructor, operator-overloading

I'm working in C# and I'm not quite sure how to word this question (which made it hard to search). Basically I have a class that inherits from `Dictionary<string,MyButton>`, where `MyButton` is a class I made. However I want to overwrite the Add function to prevent adding keyvalue pairs that don't meet specific requirements (e.x. all MyButton values in the dictionary have size properties of which are all the same). I know how to overwrite the Add function with the `New` operator however I'm not sure how to overwrite the constructor of the Dictionary class that allows one to do this, for example:

```
    Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"cat", 2},
        {"dog", 1},
        {"llama", 0},
        {"iguana", -1}
    };
```

[(Example taken from here)](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

I'm not sure which constructor allows you to do the above. I believe it's [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz.aspx) but I'm not sure how to override it, or even how to make one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That is Collection initializer for the dictionary - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531208.aspx

Comment: It's not a constructor it's an initializer and I don't think you can write your own.

Answer (score 2):

The code example you provided uses an object initialiser. This is what is termed as compiler 'sugar', i.e. it is a shorthand syntax that is expanded into the long-hand equivalent. In this case, it is shorthand for the following:

```
Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
d.Add("cat", 2);
d.Add("dog", 10);
d.Add("llama", 0);
d.Add("iguana", -1);
```

So, it is the no-arg constructor of dictionary which is being used in this case.

Also, using the `new` keyword hides the superclass method rather than override it. I would not recommend it. See this related question:

[Override Dictionary.Add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250706/override-dictionary-add)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [KeyedCollection{TKey, TItem}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) class. It is meant to be used as a base class for key-vaue collections. Then you can override protected methods InsertItem, RemoveItem, ClearItems, and SetItem to add your custom logic. These methods are called by Add, Remove and Clear methods. Look at the second example.