# Strange behavior of indexer in custom Dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have made a custom Dictionary class which inherits from Dictionary. However, strange things happen when calling the indexer depending on how I use the class. Here's a simplified version of the class:

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            return base[key];
        }
        set
        {
            base[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to create an instance and add something to it.
The following works fine, i.e. I can set a breakpoint in the setter of the indexer and it will be hit.

```
MyDictionary<int, string> dict = new MyDictionary<int, string>();
dict[0] = "some value";
```

However, if I do it like this (instantiate into an IDictionary variable):

```
IDictionary<int, string> dict = new MyDictionary<int, string>();
dict[0] = "some value";
```

it will no longer hit my breakpoint in the setter of the indexer, i.e. it must be calling something else. If I take a look at .NET's Dictionary implementation (from which my class inherit) I can find no other indexer than the one I override, and it doesn't inherit from anything else.
So the question is, what is going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override Dictionary.Add](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250706/override-dictionary-add)

Comment: I dont see how is this a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The point is in the `new` keyword in your indexer declaration. This doesn't override base class indexer and every time you access indexer from a base class or interface (like `IDictionary` in your example) - indexer of a base class would be called. Moreover, you can't override base class indexer, because it doesn't marked as `virtual` in `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class definition

consider this article on [new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) in method declaration

Try to use composition here, instead of inheritance.

If you are sure, that you need custom behavior for exactly `IDictionary<TKey, TValue` and not more abstract interfaces, like `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` or even  `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, use next example:

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    //LOTS of other methods here, that are required by IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    //their implementation would be delegation to dictionary instance

    public TValue this[TKey key] //implementation of a interface
    {
        get
        {
            return dictionary[key];
        }
        set
        {
            dictionary[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jodha sorry, I'm trying to search msdn, construct a composition example, fix spelling, answer this comment and all in parallel

Comment: After I wrote this question it occurred to me that it would be something like that (where it calls the base indexer). Then I got the idea to explicitly implement the IDictionary interface in my derived class. This actually solves the problem. But I think that your suggestion about using composition may be a better idea anyway.

Comment: because you don't need to reimplement **LOTS** of functionality defined in  `Dictionary` , you want just to delegate to it, hiding the fact, that you use concrete `Dictionary` implementation internally

Comment: Oh, and just to clarify on my comment, what I meant was doing like this: public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.

Comment: @maze_dk nice solution, but one drawback - if your reference is of type `Dictionary` - base class indexer will be called. As is ok if you reference vid `IDictionary`

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Very true. So your composition suggestion would be a better solution, although it does require more code as you mention.