# Shift all values of Dictionary to a new key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a generic dictionary which stores a *Tile* definition for each coordinate in a map of my grid-based game.

```
Dictionary<IntVector2, Tile> tiles;
```

The map can be arbitrarily sized with this setup, since new coordinates can just be added without changing anything else. However, I would like to use the (0,0) coordinate as a map pivot for other calculations, which requires me to be able to change the the map center coordinate after a map was created.

Is there a cleaner and more performant way to shift all values (*Tile*) within the dictionary to new coordinates, create new keys if necessary and delete all unused ones afterwards?

So far I have this:

```
public void MovePivot(int xDelta, int yDelta)
{
    // Copy my existing tile map.
    Dictionary<IntVector2, Tile> tilesCopy = new Dictionary<IntVector2, Tile>(tiles);

    // Initialize a new empty one.
    tiles = new Dictionary<IntVector2, Tile>();

    // Copy all old values into the new one, but shift each coordinate.
    foreach (var tile in tilesCopy)
    {
        IntVector2 newKey = tile.Key + new IntVector2(xDelta, yDelta);
        tiles.Add(newKey, tile.Value);
    }
}
```

Would this be possible "in place" without copying my dictionary?

Comment: Probably not safely anyway, unless you can guarantee that the act of "shifting" the keys will not produce keys that would overlap with existing keys.

Comment: Would it work to create a class that wraps Dictionary and privately maintains the current x,y offset?  Then the dictionary elements never need to be shifted.  Instead, at each dictionary access, the current offset is applied transparently.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. The only drawback I see, is that it adds a tiny bit of complexity to the system, because I would need to make sure that the offset is applied correctly for every method that changes tiles. Also debugging info at breakpoints might be slightly more difficult to interpret.

Comment: If you wrap dictionary into another class as @crokusek suggested, and dont expose the inner dictionary to the outside world, it can be kept simple.

Comment: @crokusek please provide the suggested answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new dictionary type can be implemented that keeps a memory of the current shift and performs the shift during read/write.

Example Usage:

```
AdjustableDictionary<int, string> map = new AdjustableDictionary<int, string>((key, adj) => key + adj);
```

This should be close.  There might be an issue with value vs reference types.

```
public class AdjustableDictionary<K, V> 
{
    public K CurrentAdjustment { get; set; }        
    public int Count { get { return _dictionary.Count; } }
    public ICollection<K> Keys { get { return _dictionary.Keys.Select(k => AdjustKey(k)).ToList(); } }

    private IDictionary<K, V> _dictionary;
    private Func<K, K, K> _adjustKey;

    public AdjustableDictionary(Func<K, K, K> keyAdjuster = null)
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<K, V>();
        _adjustKey = keyAdjuster;
    }

    public void Add(K key, V value)
    {
        _dictionary.Add(AdjustKey(key), value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(K key)
    {
        return _dictionary.ContainsKey(AdjustKey(key));
    }

    public bool Remove(K key)
    {
        return _dictionary.Remove(AdjustKey(key));
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(K key, out V value)
    {
        return _dictionary.TryGetValue(AdjustKey(key), out value);
    }

    public ICollection<V> Values { get { return _dictionary.Values; } }

    public V this[K key] {
        get {
            return _dictionary[AdjustKey(key)];
        }
        set {
            _dictionary[AdjustKey(key)] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dictionary.Clear();
    }

    private K AdjustKey(K key)
    {
        return _adjustKey != null
            ? _adjustKey(key, CurrentAdjustment)
            : key;
    }
}
```

The above code was mostly modified from this [VirtualDictionary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28179965/538763)