# Avoiding boxing/unboxing in Dictionary with object TValue

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, boxing, unboxing

Sometimes we need to store a collection of key value pairs in dictionary with various value types. Suppose we want to store a form which consist with boolean, int, string values. Some of these values are kind of **ValueType** and when we cast them to a **ReferenceType** such as `object` it causes boxing.

According to these references:

- [.NET Performance Tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/performance-tips#boxing-and-unboxing)
- [How To Avoid Boxing And Unboxing In C#](https://mdfarragher.com/2017/10/30/boxing-and-unboxing-in-csharp/)

Boxing and Unboxing impact our our performance such as GC pressure. The question is is there any way to avoiding boxing/unboxing in Dictionary which its `TValue` is `object`.

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```

How to avoiding boxing and unboxing in this scenario?

Comment: If the keys are constant, use a class. Are the keys constant?

Comment: @Sweeper The keys aren't constant.

Comment: I think the scenario isn't complete just by writing `Dictionary<string, object>`. Things like: what would you like to store in it? If you just want to store some int's, you should use `Dictionary<string, int>` instead. If you store an `int` into a `Dictionary<string, object>`, yep, it will be boxed.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen As I said, suppose a form with various value types, so here we haven't any constant type such as `int`, it could be anything. In my usage I use this dictionary to store a request form items in a logging system, it's a hot path with dozens of request and boxing/unboxing impact my application performance. The problem is we don't know the values types so we have to use `object` therefore the boxing process happens an then the main problem *low performance* code in a critical situation.

Comment: Something like: `myDictionary["name"] = "John"; myDictionary["age"] = 30;`? If this is what you're doing, I agree on the question @Sweeper, Your answer was, they aren't constant. I think, if the performance request is that high, you shouldn't use a dictionary for this. The keys aren't constant across different forms, create a class per form.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen no, consider I'm fetching items form `Request.Form` and add them to a dictionary.

Comment: How do you access the items of this dictionary? Do you know the type of the value when you request a key? Is it viable to have a method `public TValue Get<TValue>(TKey key)`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I add `Request.Form` items to my dictionary in a `foreach` and I'm not aware what is type of the form items.

Comment: If you have to use the API of a `Dictionary<string, object>`, I don't see how you can avoid the boxing of the values. Even if the values are stored internally in strongly typed containers, you want to get them back as objects, by using the indexer `public object this[string key]` or the `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`. It is an unsolvable problem IMHO.

Comment: Are you talking about the [`HttpRequest.Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.form) property? This one returns a `NameValueCollection` that only has strings as values. Another question: how many items are stored typically in one of the `Dictionary<string, object>` you are currently using? A few dozens or thousands/millions?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes but it's not just about `Request.Form`, it's general. I don't wanna store int, boolean types as string this is why I didn't mention `Request.Form` in question. I have about six `Dictionary<string, object>` that stores items in 20/30 rang in 5K RPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid **storing** multiple boxed instances of the same values by implementing a cache of pre-boxed values that are used frequently. For example if the number `0` and the boolean `false` are inserted frequently as values, you could implement a memory-optimized dictionary like this:

```
public sealed class ObjectDictionary<TKey> : Dictionary<TKey, object>
{
    private readonly object _cached_0 = 0;
    private readonly object _cached_false = false;

    public new void Add(TKey key, object value)
    {
        if (value is int && (int)value == 0)
        {
            base.Add(key, _cached_0);
        }
        else if (value is bool && (bool)value == false)
        {
            base.Add(key, _cached_false);
        }
        else
        {
            base.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The original boxed zeros and falses that are passed to the `Add` method will then be eligible for garbage collection immediately, since they won't be stored inside the dictionary. If this is still a problem for the garbage collector, then the origin of the problem is not the dictionary but something else.

Note that inheriting from [`Dictionary<TKey, object>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) is probably [not a very good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250706/override-dictionary-add/6250932#6250932). The code sample above is just for demonstration of the concept.